# Discrepancy between deliver vs deliver! methods (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-4

I've noticed via trail and error that

```
UserMailer.newsletter(@user, @posts).deliver unless @posts.blank?
```

will send the email regardless of the value of @post, while

```
UserMailer.newsletter(@user, @posts).deliver! unless @posts.blank?
```

(using deliver! vs deliver) will correctly not send the email if @posts is blank?

Why is this? I know deliver! throws an exception if it cannot be sent, but shouldn't deliver also listen to the condition?

Comment: _regardless of the value of *@post*_. Did you mean *@posts*?

Comment: yes, that was a typo!

Answer (score 5):

Use [`source_location`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Method.html#method-i-source_location) to find where a method is defined:

```
UserMailer.newsletter(@user, @posts).method(:deliver).source_location
=> ["gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb", 229]
```

This points you to [these lines in the mail gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/cbe59dc8f98c3cd54c960312a1e080ea5b9f460d/lib/mail/message.rb#L223-251) and gives you the answer:

**`deliver!` bypasses checking perform_deliveries and raise_delivery_errors.**